# Probability - Calculate P(B|C)

Tags: probability

I was trying to solve a question, and now I'm starting to think that I can't calculate, but I don't know how to prove that I can't calculate.

Well lets go to the question: Consider the events $A$, $B$ and $C$ defined on the same sample space satisfying:

- $P(A) = 0.5$;
- $P(B) = 0.2$;
- $P( A \cap B) =  0.1$;
- $P(A \cap B \cap C) = 0.1$;
- $P(B \cap C) = 0.2$;
- $P(A \cup B \cup C) = 0.9$.

**Calculate $P(B|C)$.**

I concluded that $B \subset C$, and I know how to calculate $P(C|B)$.
How can I calculate $P(B|C)$ or show that I can't calculate this?

OBS: It's my first question here, and English isn't my native language, so if i wrote something wrong, sorry.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Have you tried to do a Venn diagram of the problem? What have you found? By the way, you can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write the equations.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I don't think there's enough information here to answer that question.  I seem to be able to create a range of scenarios where $P(C)$ is somewhere in the interval $[1/2, 9/10]$, and since $P(B \mid C) = P(B \cap C)/P(C)$, that puts $P(B \mid C)$ in the interval $[1/9, 1/5]$.

Comment: I agree with @BrianTung except $P(B|C)$ is in the interval $[2/9,2/5]$ as $0.2/0.5=2/5$ and $0.2/(9/10)=2/9$

Comment: @PeterForeman: Oops, you're absolutely right.  I took $P(A \cap B)$ instead of $P(B \cap C)$.